# How to fix android SDK is missing?

Tags: android

I just start learning android and when I start a new project it shows

[Android SDK is missing , out of date or corrupted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pulMH.png)

after click 'open sdk manager'

[Android SDK setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oSCGp.png)

I can not select the sdk tabs

after click edit, show like this and I can not select 'Android SDK (installed)'

[SDK setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2eAaF.png)
also , here I have tried to add a new folder
[SDK setup with new folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YcL8S.png)
only can click next
after all nothing updated

[Nothing to do!
Android SDK is up to date.
SDK emulator directory is missing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7eGwo.png)

so how can I fix these?
(links are imgs)

Comment: You could copy the error message to avoid posting images.

Answer (score 0):

go to your SDK Manager and change the directory, make a new folder name the folder sdk and select it for your SDK directory, download the sdk file it should work
this error usually occurs because the directory is in the root folder of the android studio

Comment: Thanks for reminding ， I tried but not work

Comment: Android Studio -> Tools -> SDK Manager

Comment: @Yamini what should I do in SDK Manager?

Answer (score 0):

for me the solution was go to :
->file
->close project
and after that it will show a message (sdk is missing )
it will suggest to install it you  click next
and that set, hope it will help you:)